# Faster or more efficient alternitave to using in_array in an if statement

Tags: php

I was wondering if there is any faster/more efficient alternative to using in_array in an if statement?

```
if (!in_array(trim($data[2]),$myArray))
```

Comment: Try with the third argument.

Comment: @Dharman Thanks! That did the trick

Comment: Have you measured how slow the current process is and if you need to speed it up? What are the timings you are getting?

Comment: @Martin I have multiple statements like this in a loop that parses multiple huge text files, this loop was giving me "Allowed memory size exhausted". I tried increasing memory size but the parser was freezing after a while. So I put in the third argument like Dharman suggested and it seems to be working fine now. I don't know if the third argument in_array makes that much of a difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `array_key_exists`  check the key in Assoc Array

```
if (array_key_exists(trim($data[2]), $myArray))
```

You can use `array_diff`

```
if (array_diff(trim($data[2]), $myArray))
```

Comment: This is the opposite

Comment: @Dharman yes you are right.array_key_exists check the key not the value and in_array check the values.Thanks